# Passing an involution to a quotient algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, universal-algebra, universal-property, involutions

This question is inspired by the discussion under [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/463103/35482). I hope I have captured correctly what is going on in the below.

Let $A_0$ be a finitely generated universal unital complex algebra $A_0=\langle \mathcal{G}\mid\mathcal{R} \rangle$. If an algebra $B$ has $|\mathcal{G}|$ generators which also satisfy the relations $\mathcal{R}$, then there exists a surjective algebra homomorphism $\pi:A_0\to B$.

If $\mathcal{R}$ consists of relations palindromic in the generators (and no complex numbers), then the complex conjugate opposite algebra $\overline{A_0^{\text{opp}}}$ satisfies the same relations it is the case that the induced homomorphism $r:A_0\to \overline{A_0^{\text{opp}}}$ is an algebra homomorphism. In this case I think we have $A_0= \overline{A_0^{\text{opp}}}$ as sets, and using this identification, $r:A_0\to A_0$, a conjugate linear map:
$$r(g_1g_2)=g_2g_1\qquad (g_1,g_2\in \mathcal{G}),$$
is in fact an involution, a star. Equipping $A_0$ with this involution, call it $A$, this is then a *-algebra.

Does this mean we can equip an algebra quotient $\pi:A_0\to B$ with a star structure? Say $$\pi(a)^*=\pi(r(a))\qquad (a\in A).$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the *-algebra setting, but in general "a ring $R$ is isomorphic to its opposite" does not imply "every quotient ring $R/I$ is isomorphic to its opposite", take e.g. [$R_{22}$](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/22/) from rschwieb's [DaRT](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/). (You did not say anything about $B$'s relations.)

Comment: The ideal by which you quotient should be a $*$-ideal.

Comment: @CaptainLama yes ideally (!), but here the quotient map is only an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist $B$ might be concrete. In context it is. I think what you are saying answers the question, will think again and get back to you.

Comment: @CaptainLama ... and given by a universal property.